# The method with the override invalidator did not invalidate any base class method

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm learning Unreal Engine 4.13.2 and C++ using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.

I think my problem is a C++ so I think the best place to ask about it is here.

I have a C++ class that inherits from AActor class. I have to override a method from AActor so I have put this on my header file:

```
virtual void ReceiveHit(class UPrimitiveComponent* MyComp, class AActor* Other, class UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, bool bSelfMoved, FVector HitLocation, FVector HitNormal, FVector NormalImpulse, const FHitResult& Hit);
```

And also I have implemented in the cpp file.

But I get the following compiler error:

> MyActor.h(23): error C3668: 'MyActor::ReceiveHit': The method with the
>   override invalidator did not invalidate any base class method

I have copied `ReceiveHit` method from AActor.h file and I get that error.

I have also another methods overridden without problems. This is `MyActor` header file:

```
#pragma once

#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "MyActor.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class MYGAME_API AMyActor : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public: 
    // Sets default values for this actor's properties
    AMyActor();

    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick( float DeltaSeconds ) override;

    virtual void ReceiveHit(class UPrimitiveComponent* MyComp, AActor* Other, class UPrimitiveComponent* OtherComp, bool bSelfMoved, FVector HitLocation, FVector HitNormal, FVector NormalImpulse, const FHitResult& Hit) override;

private:
    UProjectileMovementComponent* MyMovement;
};
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/AActor/ReceiveHit/index.html) the function is not virtual, so you can't override it

Comment: @UnholySheep Maybe I have followed an old tutorial.

Comment: @UnholySheep Look at this: https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Reflecting_Projectile_C%2B%2B. Here, ReceiveHit is defined as virtual. So, I don't need to use override to implement it, isn't it? Do I have to call Super::ReceiveHit?

Comment: Check the definition in the header you are building against. The compiler is telling you its not virtual, or at least the signature that you have specified to override is not virtual. Maybe the interface has changed?

Comment: Yes. No need to delete! It's a valid question IMO and demonstrates the importance of override! Also docs - https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/AActor/NotifyHit/index.html

Comment: Ok. They have changed ReceiveHit with NotifyHit. What a mess!!! Thanks a lot for your time. I will delete this question.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you write `class UPrimitiveComponent* MyComp` rather than `UPrimitiveComponent* MyComp`?

Comment: @ChristianHackl No, I have only copy and paste ReceiveHit from AActor header. I'm learning C++ also, so I'm not sure if it is right or wrong. I think they have put class in method signature because they don't have put the `#include` statement.

Comment: @VansFannel: It is mainly C heritage, almost always unnecessary in C++ and thus very surprising to see. It has nothing to do with the `#include` statements.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Is that `class` thing you mentioned the same as this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28007165/class-keyword-in-variable-definition-in-c

If so, I think Unreal Engine uses it very often due to their coding style, they use capital letter for their variable name as well, so they often need to put the `class` keyword in front of the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that this is not a virtual method. They've changed the API and I was following an old example.

No, I can use [NotifyHit](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/AActor/NotifyHit/index.html) that is virtual and I can override it:

```
virtual void NotifyHit
(
    class UPrimitiveComponent * MyComp,
    AActor * Other,
    class UPrimitiveComponent * OtherComp,
    bool bSelfMoved,
    FVector HitLocation,
    FVector HitNormal,
    FVector NormalImpulse,
    const FHitResult & Hit
)
```